# SQL Server Sub-query with min and Max values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm having considerable difficulty understanding and using a nested subquery in T-SQL (SQL Server 2012):

- Customer Name
- Customer Number
- Date of first sale
- Date of last sale

I can create the table showing EITHER Min(sale_date) or Max(Sale_date using the below query but not both.

```
select 
    cm_number, cm_name, dim_invoice_date
from 
    fact_invoice_history
where 
    fact_invoice_history.dim_invoice_date = (select MAX(fact_invoice_history.dim_invoice_date) 
                                             from fact_invoice_history)
```

Please help. I know that this is a bit of a beginner question.

Comment: I suspect that you want this for each  cm_number?  (and not overall in fact_invoice_history).  Have you looked into Group By  ?

Comment: Yes, i'd absolutely need this to be by individual cm_number, not the max of the entire history. Thanks for the clarficiation.

How would a group by help? the Max date of sale would still be a distinct single value, not an aggregate. Same with Min date of sale

If i wanted to add the total value sold per cm_number I'd see the need, otherwise i'm not sure the value. Can you maybe elaborate a little?

Comment: or is it as simple as

select cm_number, cm_name, min(dim_invoice_date), max(dim_invoice_date)

from fact_invoice_history

Comment: What happens when you try that, along with Group By cm_number?  Then we also need max(cm_name).

Comment: So you want two records for each customer, one for first sale date and one for last sale date, or do you want a single record for each customer, containing both the first and the last sale dates?

Comment: hi all,
thanks for the assist. Solved.

Comment: Please share with what worked

Comment: @Boothy_79 If you've managed to solve your problem then please either post the solution as an answer and accept it once you can (there's is a time period to wait for accepting self answers) so that other people will know that the problem is solved, or delete the question entirely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * into #fact_invoice_history from
    (select 1 as cm_number, 'one' as cm_name, '2018-09-01 10:15:00' as dim_invoice_date
    union all select 1, 'one', '2018-09-02 10:15:00'
    union all select 1, 'one', '2018-09-03 10:15:00'
    union all select 2, 'two', '2018-09-06 10:15:00'
    union all select 2, 'two', '2018-09-07 10:15:00'
    union all select 3, 'three', '2018-09-08 10:15:00') data

select * from #fact_invoice_history
-- ----------------------------------------
--  cm_number   cm_name dim_invoice_date
--  ----------- ------- -------------------
--  1           one     2018-09-01 10:15:00
--  1           one     2018-09-02 10:15:00
--  1           one     2018-09-03 10:15:00
--  2           two     2018-09-06 10:15:00
--  2           two     2018-09-07 10:15:00
--  3           three   2018-09-08 10:15:00
-- ----------------------------------------

select 
    cm_number,
    cm_name,
    min(dim_invoice_date) min_sale_date,
    max(dim_invoice_date) max_sale_date
from 
    #fact_invoice_history
group by
    cm_number,
    cm_name
-- ------------------------------------------------------------
--  cm_number   cm_name min_sale_date       max_sale_date
--  ----------- ------- ------------------- -------------------
--  1           one     2018-09-01 10:15:00 2018-09-03 10:15:00
--  3           three   2018-09-08 10:15:00 2018-09-08 10:15:00
--  2           two     2018-09-06 10:15:00 2018-09-07 10:15:00
-- ------------------------------------------------------------

drop table #fact_invoice_history
```

Answer (score 0):

the below solution worked fine.

```
    select 
    cm_number,
    cm_name,
    min(dim_invoice_date) min_sale_date,
    max(dim_invoice_date) max_sale_date
from 
    #fact_invoice_history
group by
    cm_number,
    cm_name
```

I probably asked the wrong question here though, but thanks for the help